# Good freeware COM/ActiveX Type Library Explorer?

Tags: com, activex

I used to have a dated, but valuable solution to display COM/ActiveX control- and type-library contents (ProgIDs, method names and signatures, enumerations, constants, interfaces/coclasses, etc.) of all such libraries registered on my system.

It provided an Explorer-like overview of everything that was available to ActiveX development/scripting and served as an automatic API documentation tool since official docs for most COM/ActiveX libraries are either missing completely or fragmentary at best.

My recent move to a 64bit Windows rendered the program I had unusable, due to internal dependencies on the 32bit VB6 runtime (comctl32.ocx) that is no longer supported on 64bit Windows.

Does anyone know an alternative that still works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest [oleviewdotnet](https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet). Not a binary; it has to be downloaded and compiled; but still extremely powerful for all that

Comment: I've downloaded and compiled it. It's a bit fiddly and fragmented, but it seems to be stable and provides all the information. The integrated Python scripting is a really nice touch.

Answer (score 6):

**OleView.exe** from Visual Studio tools. It does the most things you described and works great on x64.

Comment: This does not work very well. Crashes often and fails to deliver much useful information. At least I've been unable to find method signatures, contstants or *anything* beyond a bunch of interface CLSIDs /GUIDs that I'm not really interested in. It does not even have search. :-\ This is frustrating. Is nobody using COM/ActiveX anymore? (Rhetorical question, I know...)

Comment: I use it rarely to get CLSID from OCX file but it never crashed. Did you try to "view" typelib and select CoClasses item? Method list and signatures are placed there. Yes, this tool is not too convenient but better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There's an open-source, freeware typelib data dumper and the 
"Unofficial TypeLib Data Format Specification" at: 
http://theircorp.byethost11.com/index.php?vw=TypeLib 

Michael

Answer (score 2):

COMView might be worth a try: http://www.japheth.de/COMView.html
But I haven't tested it personally. The web page don't say anything about x64 but as the last version isn't that old (2011) it might work.